# Proving units in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

> Suppose $R$ is a ring with no zero divisors and with identity $1_R$ not equal to $0_R$.  Suppose that $a,b$ are in $R$ and that $ab$ is a unit.  Prove that $b$ is a unit.

My thoughts: I know a unit is basically a unit that (for this example) would mean $abu = 1_R$ for some nonzero $u$ in $R$.  I am really stuck after that.  Not seeing a clear path to manipulate the variables to prove b is a unit by itself.

Comment: Well, write it this way: $\;1=u(ab)=(ua)b\implies b\;$ is a unit...:)

Comment: @Don That yields only a *left* inverse $\,c = ua\,$ for $\,b.\,$ But conjugation shows it is a *right* inverse too - see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

As the others have pointed out the calculation
$$
1=u(ab)=(ua)b
$$
shows that $ua$ is a left inverse to $b$. Consider the product $b(ua)$. We have
$$
ua=1(ua)=((ua)b)(ua)=(ua)(b(ua)),
$$
so
$$
(ua)(1-b(ua))=0.
$$
As the ring has no zero divisors this implies that either $ua=0$ or $b(ua)=1$. But
if $(ua)=0$, then $1=(ua)b=0$ which is a contradiction. The claim follows.

Comment: +1 for actually using the fact the ring has no zero divisors...

Comment: @Goos: Well, the claim is false without something extra, and that was the only piece available :-) All: Sorry about spoiling the problem. I really should have come up with an appropriate hint.

Comment: yes, but there were two maybe three people claiming "solutions" without using that fact.  So +1 for a legitimate proof that it is a unit and not just having a left inverse.

Comment: @Jyrki Re: hints. See my answer for one way I often hint at it. It's not easy to give a hint for this without spilling the beans.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments, since $ab$ is a unit then $uab = 1$ for some $u \in R$, so $ua$ is a left inverse for $b$.  It remains to show that $ua$ is also a right inverse for $b$, i.e., $bua = 1$.  Taking the equation $1 = uab$ and multiplying both sides by $ua$ on the right, we have
$$
ua = uabua \implies 0 = ua - uabua = ua(1 - bua) \, .
$$
Since $R$ has no zero divisors, then either $ua = 0$ or $1 - bua = 0$.  But again, $R$ has no zero divisors, so we must have $1 - bua = 0$, hence $1 = bua$.  Thus $ua$ is a two-sided inverse for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ *Conjugate* a one-sided inverse $\,bc=1\,$  to the other side via $\ (bc\!-\!1)b\, =\, b(cb\!-\!1)$